# Jupyter: How to always immediately see my graph modifications without scrolling?

Tags: charts, jupyter-notebook

The Jupyter notebooks have the very nice interactive graphics display with the magic:

```
%matplotlib notebook
```

With it, your charts are always updated for each new command.

My problem is that when I continue to plot new things, the graph scrolls out view. When I run a new command, like plt.set_title, I have to scroll up to see if my modification worked as expected.

Is it possible to have the chart always displayed, without the need to scroll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to start to use new generation of notebooks: [Jupyter Lab](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab).

You can open another view of the same notebook. In one view you would have your image output, in the other one the code.

[image: Jupyter with 2 views]